# How to add translation support to Django constants?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a Django application with some dictionaries defined in `constants.py`.

The values in the dictionary represent user-readable labels, and I want to add translation support, so Django i18n feature than auto-translate them based on locale.

So I added to the top of my constants.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

and then applied it like:

```
{
    "code": _("some name to be translated"),
    ....
}
```

That seems to have worked somewhat, put I'm running into problems with Celery and multi-processing support, or anything that tries to import my models in anything but the most vanilla manner.

Specifically, when trying to do any kind of multi-processing, Django now throws the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

which is itself caused by a different error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

and the traceback for that starts at my use of `gettext_lazy` in `constants.py`.

So clearly, something I'm doing is not copacetic.

Is there a best practice to applying translation support to constants in Django?

Answer (score 0):

This page has a throughout tutorial that might be, if well not the answer to your question, the answer to your problem: https://pypi.org/project/django-parler/

It requires you to familiarize with a new tool; but will save you some time in the long run.